# Convert from PDT to GMT or PST to GMT based date-time in the Column of a Table

Tags: oracle, date

I am stuck with a finding out and converting date from one of my database column. The database I am using is Oracle.

My database column saves the data in PST or PDT depending on the time of the year the entry was done.

For example - in US the local time changes from PST to PDT at 02:00 LST to 03:00 LDT on the second Sunday in March and the time returns at 02:00 LDT to 01:00 LST on the first Sunday in November.

So in my target i have one extra column which will be storing the date in GMT format.

So please help me to handle the situation and store the result from Source to target.

Source table:

```
Request_ID, Requested_by, Added_Day
```

Target table:

```
Request_ID, Requested_by, Added_Day, Added_Day_INGMT
```

The Added Day in the Source will have data in PDT as well as PST based on the day it got added as explained in above example.

And in Target i want the corresponding Added_day to be saved in Added_Day_INGMT after converting it to GMT.

Please help me to do it. I am clueless because the same column has data for PDT as well as PST and it has to be handled accordingly while converting it to GMT

Thanks.

Comment: What is the data type of these columns?

Comment: Request_ID NUMBER(26), Requested_by VARCHAR(30),Added_Day DATE,Added_Day_INGMT DATE

Comment: If you have a *date* value of 2017-11-05 01:30:00, that could originally have been either PDT or PST. There is no way to tell now. How should that be converted to GMT?

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to copy the data into a new table then you can do:

```
insert into target (request_id, requested_by, added_day, added_day_ingmt)
select request_id, requested_by, added_day,
  cast(sys_extract_utc(from_tz(cast(added_day as timestamp), 'America/Los_Angeles')) as date)
from source;
```

which is the same conversion @Wernfried showed (aside from going West-coast); I've done an explicit cast to date at the end though that isn't really necessary if the target column is a date as it would be implicitly converted.

Quick demo:

```
create table source (request_id, requested_by, added_day) as
          select 1, 'Anon', cast(timestamp '2017-11-05 01:00:00' as date) from dual
union all select 2, 'Anon', cast(timestamp '2017-11-05 01:59:59' as date) from dual
union all select 3, 'Anon', cast(timestamp '2017-11-05 02:00:00' as date) from dual
union all select 4, 'Anon', cast(timestamp '2017-11-05 02:59:59' as date) from dual
union all select 5, 'Anon', cast(timestamp '2017-11-05 03:00:00' as date) from dual
union all select 6, 'Anon', cast(timestamp '2018-03-11 00:59:59' as date) from dual
union all select 7, 'Anon', cast(timestamp '2018-03-11 01:00:00' as date) from dual
union all select 8, 'Anon', cast(timestamp '2018-03-11 01:59:59' as date) from dual
union all select 9, 'Anon', cast(timestamp '2018-03-11 03:00:00' as date) from dual;

create table target (request_id number(25), requested_by varchar2(30), added_day date,
  added_day_ingmt date);

alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1 TZH:TZM';
```

You can see the conversion steps with:

```
select request_id, requested_by, added_day,
  from_tz(cast(added_day as timestamp), 'America/Los_Angeles'),
  from_tz(cast(added_day as timestamp), 'America/Los_Angeles') at time zone 'UTC',
  sys_extract_utc(from_tz(cast(added_day as timestamp), 'America/Los_Angeles')),
  cast(sys_extract_utc(from_tz(cast(added_day as timestamp), 'America/Los_Angeles')) as date)
from source;

REQUEST_ID REQU ADDED_DAY           FROM_TZ(CAST(ADDED_DAYASTIME FROM_TZ(CAST(ADDED_DAYASTIME SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_ CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UT
---------- ---- ------------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- --------------------- -------------------
         1 Anon 2017-11-05 01:00:00 2017-11-05 01:00:00.0 -08:00 2017-11-05 09:00:00.0 +00:00 2017-11-05 09:00:00.0 2017-11-05 09:00:00
         2 Anon 2017-11-05 01:59:59 2017-11-05 01:59:59.0 -08:00 2017-11-05 09:59:59.0 +00:00 2017-11-05 09:59:59.0 2017-11-05 09:59:59
         3 Anon 2017-11-05 02:00:00 2017-11-05 02:00:00.0 -08:00 2017-11-05 10:00:00.0 +00:00 2017-11-05 10:00:00.0 2017-11-05 10:00:00
         4 Anon 2017-11-05 02:59:59 2017-11-05 02:59:59.0 -08:00 2017-11-05 10:59:59.0 +00:00 2017-11-05 10:59:59.0 2017-11-05 10:59:59
         5 Anon 2017-11-05 03:00:00 2017-11-05 03:00:00.0 -08:00 2017-11-05 11:00:00.0 +00:00 2017-11-05 11:00:00.0 2017-11-05 11:00:00
         6 Anon 2018-03-11 00:59:59 2018-03-11 00:59:59.0 -08:00 2018-03-11 08:59:59.0 +00:00 2018-03-11 08:59:59.0 2018-03-11 08:59:59
         7 Anon 2018-03-11 01:00:00 2018-03-11 01:00:00.0 -08:00 2018-03-11 09:00:00.0 +00:00 2018-03-11 09:00:00.0 2018-03-11 09:00:00
         8 Anon 2018-03-11 01:59:59 2018-03-11 01:59:59.0 -08:00 2018-03-11 09:59:59.0 +00:00 2018-03-11 09:59:59.0 2018-03-11 09:59:59
         9 Anon 2018-03-11 03:00:00 2018-03-11 03:00:00.0 -07:00 2018-03-11 10:00:00.0 +00:00 2018-03-11 10:00:00.0 2018-03-11 10:00:00
```

and running the insert above inserts nine rows, which gives you:

```
select * from target;

REQUEST_ID REQUESTED_BY                   ADDED_DAY           ADDED_DAY_INGMT    
---------- ------------------------------ ------------------- -------------------
         1 Anon                           2017-11-05 01:00:00 2017-11-05 09:00:00
         2 Anon                           2017-11-05 01:59:59 2017-11-05 09:59:59
         3 Anon                           2017-11-05 02:00:00 2017-11-05 10:00:00
         4 Anon                           2017-11-05 02:59:59 2017-11-05 10:59:59
         5 Anon                           2017-11-05 03:00:00 2017-11-05 11:00:00
         6 Anon                           2018-03-11 00:59:59 2018-03-11 08:59:59
         7 Anon                           2018-03-11 01:00:00 2018-03-11 09:00:00
         8 Anon                           2018-03-11 01:59:59 2018-03-11 09:59:59
         9 Anon                           2018-03-11 03:00:00 2018-03-11 10:00:00
```

You can't fix the ambiguity of the times during the PDT->PST switch though, as that hour is repeated - without the original time zone information you don't know which of the two possible GMT/UTC times anything in that hour actually refers to.

To demonstrate that ambiguity:

```
with t (tsz) as (
            select timestamp '2017-11-05 01:30:00 America/Los_Angeles PDT' from dual
  union all select timestamp '2017-11-05 01:30:00 America/Los_Angeles PST' from dual
)
select tsz, cast(tsz as date), from_tz(cast(tsz as timestamp), 'America/Los_Angeles')
from t;

TSZ                          CAST(TSZASDATE)     FROM_TZ(CAST(TSZASTIMESTAMP)
---------------------------- ------------------- ----------------------------
2017-11-05 01:30:00.0 -07:00 2017-11-05 01:30:00 2017-11-05 01:30:00.0 -08:00
2017-11-05 01:30:00.0 -08:00 2017-11-05 01:30:00 2017-11-05 01:30:00.0 -08:00
```

Starting with 01:30 in either PDT or PST converts to a date or timestamp at 01:30 with no time zone information; converting bask to the time zone Oracle has to pick which to use. Regardless of the original DST situation, you end up with a value in PST - or in your case, the same value in UTC - even though they were originally an hour apart.

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-7ECF5B82-C3B5-4873-AC78-61080C8F756A):

> ... ambiguous datetime values are assumed to be the standard time representation for the region

If you set `ERROR_ON_OVERLAP_TIME` to `TRUE` in your session then it would error on those ambiguous values instead.

Comment: How the following is handled in this can u explain ??? in US the local time changes from PST to PDT at 02:00 LST to 03:00 LDT on the second Sunday in March and the time returns at 02:00 LDT to 01:00 LST on the first Sunday in November.

Comment: That's the point of the last bit of my answer. The database knows about DST changes so `systimerstamp` always show the correct time and zome; `sysdate` always shows the correct time, but with no time zone information. So if you query `sysdate` for a few hours over the clock change in November it will show 01:00:00, ..., 01:59:59, 01:00:00, 01:00:01, ..., 01:59:59, 02:00:00. The same times are repeated for that hour. They represent different actual points in universal time, but as you've lost the time zone information you cannot tell which you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You could add virtual column like this:

```
Added_Day_INGMT DATE GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST(Added_Day AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York'))) VIRTUAL
```

However, times as expressed by Alex Poole will not work. For such timestamps there is no solution since `DATE` data type does not provide any time zone information.